# How to use pigpio to control a servo motor with a keyboard?

Tags: python, pwm, servo, pigpio

My aim is to be able to control a servo motor with my keyboard in a real time fashion using the **python module** of **pigpio**. That is, when I press say the 'w' key it rotates clockwise and when I press the 's' key anticlockwise. I'm using an **RPi 2, a tower Pro Micro servo SG90** and have connected it to the **PWM enabled pin 13** (BCM denotation). My servo has **not** been modified for continuous rotation.
My requests are:

- A python code using pigpio to achieve this (or guidelines to do the same)
- Is it possible for me to change the speed with which the servo rotates? As far as I understand it can be done using a `for` loop. If possible please allow that in the code

To use the keyboard I've tried reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-in-python) but am not able to decipher it. I've also tried going through the pigpio documentation and have managed to move the servo to a specific orientation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if anyone will write the code for you.  It's too broad a question.

You need to acquire a basic understanding of Python programming first, otherwise you'll be forever asking questions.

Personally I'd use the Python curses module (import curses) to handle keyboard entry.  There are example of using curses within pigpio at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/gpio_status_py.zip and http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/PCF8591.zip.

On the servo speed.  Generally the speed of continuous rotation servos is controlled by the pulse width.  1500µs is the dead band and means stop (perhaps controlled by a trimming screw in the servo housing).  As you increase the pulse width to 2000µs the servo goes faster and faster in one direction.  As you decrease the pulse width to 1000µs the servo goes faster and faster in the other direction.

```
1000µs     1250µs     1500µs     1750µs     2000µs
fastest    fast       stop       fast       fastest
anti-      anti-                 clockwise  clockwise
clockwise  clockwise
```

---

Edited to add example code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# servo_key.py
# 2015-04-10
# Public Domain

import time
import curses
import atexit

import pigpio 

SERVO = 4

MIN_PW = 1000
MID_PW = 1500
MAX_PW = 2000

NONE        = 0
LEFT_ARROW  = 1
RIGHT_ARROW = 2
UP_ARROW    = 3
DOWN_ARROW  = 4
HOME        = 5
QUIT        = 6

def getch():
   global in_escape, in_cursor
   c = stdscr.getch()

   key = NONE

   if c == 27:
      in_escape = True
      in_cursor = False
   elif c == 91 and in_escape:
      in_cursor = True
   elif c == 68 and in_cursor:
      key = LEFT_ARROW
      in_escape = False
   elif c == 67 and in_cursor:
      key = RIGHT_ARROW
      in_escape = False
   elif c == 65 and in_cursor:
      key = UP_ARROW
      in_escape = False
   elif c == 66 and in_cursor:
      key = DOWN_ARROW
      in_escape = False
   elif c == 72 and in_cursor:
      key = HOME
      in_escape = False
   elif c == 113 or c == 81:
      key = QUIT
   else:
      in_escape = False
      in_cursor = False

   return key

def cleanup():
   curses.nocbreak()
   curses.echo()
   curses.endwin()
   pi.stop()

pi = pigpio.pi()

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()

atexit.register(cleanup) # Ensure original screen state is restored.

in_escape = False
in_cursor = False

pulsewidth = MID_PW

pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, pulsewidth)

while True:

   time.sleep(0.01)

   c = getch()

   if c == QUIT:
      break

   pw = pulsewidth

   if c == HOME:
      pw = MID_PW # Stop.
   elif c == UP_ARROW:
      pw = MAX_PW # Fastest clockwise.
   elif c == DOWN_ARROW:
      pw = MIN_PW # Fastest anti-clockwise
   elif c == LEFT_ARROW:
      pw = pw - 5 # Shorten pulse.
      if pw < MIN_PW:
         pw = MIN_PW
   elif c == RIGHT_ARROW:
      pw = pw + 5 # Lengthen pulse.
      if pw > MAX_PW:
         pw = MAX_PW

   if pw != pulsewidth:
      pulsewidth = pw
      pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, pulsewidth)
```

Comment: Isn't the curses module more for enabling screen manipulation? Is there a simpler module which I can use to achieve the same?

Comment: @VishaalDevanaboyina As you say it's probably used more for screen displays.  Let me have a look at some alternatives and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok, please do tell if anything crops up. By the way, excellent work on pigpio!

Comment: I still think curses is the better choice.  I misread your original question and thought you did have a continuous rotation servo.  I have edited my post to add code assuming a continuous rotation servo.  Have a look and see if you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Curses is a *terminal* library, which includes output (the screen) and input.   This is a pretty standard use for it.

Comment: @joan Will do so and get back with the results.
Yes, I stand corrected, I've done a little more research on curses and this seems to be a common use for it.